# Problem with validateattributes function in Octave

Tags: matlab, parsing, input, octave

I am trying to port some MATLAB code from GitHub to Octave and having problems with parsing the function input. There is/are optional input parameters which are handled thus:

```
% Optional parameter: maxLag
defaultMaxLag = 10 ;
checkMaxLag = @(x) validateattributes( x , { 'numeric' } , { 'positive' , 'numel' , 1 } ) ;
```

which are then handled by the `inputParser`:

```
addOptional( parser , 'maxLag' , defaultMaxLag , checkMaxLag ) ;
```

If I try running this code as is I get the error

```
error: mdDelay: argument 'MAXLAG' is not a valid parameter
```

My Octave translation of this last code snippet is

```
addParamValue( parser , 'maxLag' , defaultMaxLag , checkMaxLag ) ;
```

which is also failing, but with the error message

```
error: if: undefined value used in conditional expression
error: called from
validate_arg at line 521 column 9
parse at line 470 column 11
```

The problem seems to be the anonymous function `checkMaxLag` because when I run just this in the terminal I get

```
error: value on right hand side of assignment is undefined
```

so it seems that `validateattributes` does not give a return value that the `inputParser` requires. Any suggestions?

Comment: Used Version? Do you think this might be important?

Comment: Octave has the `addOptional` method. There's no need to change your code to use `addParamValue` instead.

Comment: @carandraug the addOptional method is also failing - please see my edit

Comment: [`validateattributes`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/validateattributes.html) does not return a value, as described in the documentation.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, and therein lies the problem. Presumably in the MATLAB environment the code works without needing a return value, but not in the Octave environment - hence my request for help in re-writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to with the change from `addOptional` to `addparamValue` to the port. The problem is simply that this fails (the error message recently on a newer version):

```
octave> validate_lag = @(x) validateattributes (x, {'numeric'}, {'positive', 'numel', 1});
octave> p = inputParser ();
octave> p.addOptional ('maxLag', 10, validate_lag);
octave> p.parse (20)
error: failed validation of MAXLAG
Validation function: @(x) validateattributes (x, {'numeric'}, {'positive', 'numel', 1})
```

You got caught by Octave's [bug #49793](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=49793). Basically, `inputParser` expects a validation function that returns true or false. However, `validateattributes` either returns nothing or fails. I recommend you do this:

```
function rv = validateattributes_with_return_value (varargin)
  try
    validateattributes (varargin{:});
    rv = true;
  catch
    rv = false;
  end_try_catch
endfunction
```

And then you can use

```
validate_lag = @(x) validateattributes_with_return_value (x, {'numeric'}, {'positive', 'numel', 1});
```

Comment: your recommendation has solved my problem; however I have still found it necessary to use addParamValue - addOptional continues to give the error outlined above.

Comment: @babelproofreader open a new question then with the minimal code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: This same bug got me on Ubuntu 22.04 with Octave 6.4.0 and matgeom 1.2.3-2.  In this case in matgeom's `rotation3dToEulerAngles()` function.   The "one-line-fix" in the linked bug fixes it.  Only commenting because it took me a while to find the solution, and this problem with matgeom doesn't seem to be mentioned elsewhere.