# addOptional in Octave 5.1.0 is failing when parsing function input

Tags: matlab, parsing, input, octave

This is a follow up to an earlier question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57679778/problem-with-validateattributes-function-in-octave). Although the immediate problem in said question has been solved by use of addParamValue and the recommendated function, there is still an issue with using addOptional. The code flow is:

```
parser = inputParser() ;
parser.FunctionName = "mdDelay" ;
defaultMaxLag = 10 ;
checkMaxLag = @(x) validateattributes_with_return_value(x, {'numeric'}, {'positive', 'numel', 1}) ;
```

where validateattributes_with_return_value is a wrapper around Octave's validateattributes so that true or false is returned

```
function retval = validateattributes_with_return_value( varargin )
  try
    validateattributes( varargin{ : } ) ;
    retval = true ;
  catch
    retval = false ;
  end_try_catch
endfunction
```

then using either of

```
addRequired( parser , 'data' , @checkdata ) ;
addOptional( parser , 'maxLag' , defaultMaxLag , checkMaxLag ) ;
```

or

```
addRequired( parser , 'data' , @checkdata ) ;
parser.addOptional( 'maxLag' , defaultMaxLag , checkMaxLag ) ;
```

where checkdata is a simple check that the input data is a numeric vector or matrix

```
function check = checkdata( x )
   check = false;
   if (~isnumeric(x))
       error('Input is not numeric');
   elseif (numel(x) <= 1)
       error('Input must be a vector or matrix');
   else
   check = true;
   end
endfunction
```

followed by

```
parse( parser , data , varargin{:} ) ;
```

fails with the error message

```
error: mdDelay: argument 'MAXLAG' is not a valid parameter
```

when called thus

```
tau = mdDelay( data , 'maxLag' , 25 ) ;
```

In this case the data is simply a 2000 row by 3 column matrix of numeric values.

I have tried changing the order the inputs appear in the code, thinking that it could be a problem with being "positional," but to no avail.

This is not a major concern as I now have functioning code using addParamValue, but maybe this highlights another known bug in Octave?

Comment: can you give the minimal code to reproduce the issue? Like, the 3 lines to reproduce it. One creates the parser, another calls `addOptional`, and the third calls `parse`.

Comment: @carandraug have added extra code snippets as requested

Comment: that's not enough. We don't know what is `checkdata`, `data`, and in `vararagin`. Even `validateattributes_with_return_value` we don't know (I know because I answered your other question but other's shouldn't have to dig through that to understand this question). Please, keep the code showing issue the minimum and complete. Get rid of the `validatateattributes` part if it makes the question too complex. Someone should be be able to copy those few lines into a new octave session and get the same error.

Comment: You can simplify the problem immensely, your question is too complex right now to see what is going on. Read [mre]. Is it `inputParser` that is misbehaving or is it `validateattributes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `addOptional` incorrectly. An optional parameter is an optional argument that is identified by its position on the list of arguments. So you should be calling it like so:

```
mdDelay (data, 25); # 25 is the value for maxLag
```

You are getting an error because your passing `'maxLag'` (the string) as the value for `maxLag` (the option):

```
mdDelay (data, 'maxLag', 25); # 'maxLag' is the value for maxLag
```

And of course `'maxLag'` fails the test:

```
checkMaxLag = @(x) validateattributes (x, {'numeric'}, {'positive', 'numel', 1}) ;
checkMaxLag('maxLag') # the string is not numeric
```

Comment: With this information I have managed to get addOptional to work. However, there may still be a difference between Octave and Matlab in this regard. I'm porting this github ( https://github.com/danm0nster/mdembedding ) and the README.md and Matlab notebook clearly show the calling convention of using the string and value together, even though the code uses addOptional. I'm assuming the authors of the github know what they're doing and have not made a mistake in the readme or notebook, hence my problem ( now solved thanks to you. )

Comment: @babelproofreader that's very weird undocumented behaviour of Matlab. I have opened an issue with mdembedding asking to not use undocumented behaviour.